# Difficulty with MechanicalSoup forms

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanicalsoup

First, I am French so if there are mistakes in my english I'm sorry. So here is my problem, I have hard time with mechanicalsoup. So here is my HTML page:

`<form class="XFYOY" method="post"><h2 class="vvzhL ">Inscrivez-vous pour voir les photos et vidéos de vos amis.</h2>`
Here are just the first line. I want to create an automatic form but there is not action and I don't know what to put in browser.select_form():

`browser.select_form('form[action=/post]')`

`browser["emailOrPhone"] = "0689754327"`

`browser["fullName"] = "Jean"`

What I put is not working because the form I have don't have a action. What can I do ?

Thx, Lazare

Comment: Can you post the link to the page you are scraping so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your form does not have an `action`, it has a uniquely identifiable attribute in `class="XDYOY"`. Therefore, you can select it with the `.XFYOY` CSS selector:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open(WEBSITE_URL)

browser.select_form(".XFYOY")
browser["emailOrPhone"] = "0689754327"
browser["fullName"] = "Jean"
browser.submit_selected()
```

You can find a list of other selectors on [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Hello, Thank for your answer ! I try it but it didn't work. Here is the website URL: www.instagram.com and it's the form to create a new account !